# Tire size on rim

Tags: tire, rims

I have bought both my girls bikes at walmart. Both bikes have tires that are bigger than the rims, but the size printed is the right size. One is a 16" bike and the other is a 18". It's just one wheel on each bike. When inflated the bottom of the tire pops out the top of the rim and doesn't seat. I would by a new tire, but I have no idea if it's actually the tire that is the problem.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Okay, I have it figured out. The tires weren't seating properly when they were being inflated. I filled them slowly and properly seated the tire to the rim as I did. They are fine now.

Comment: you might want to post that comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the empty tire is not seated properly on the rim, so it's a good idea to inflate it a little bit first and check it, before inflating it fully.

This is one of these things where it's helpful if somebody shows you how to do it, especially if you're doing it for the first time, because there are little tricks that experienced people use naturally, but that are not so obvious to novices and hard to explain in words.

I found the Parktool videos quite good for this, and these two show you (towards the end) how to inflate a tire and make sure it sits properly:

The second one also shows you how to fix a puncture which is worth learning (if you're new to cycling) because it's quite likely you'll need it some time.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was. After I let the air out it was very obvious it hadn't previously seated properly. Thanks.